# Annotation Drag and Drop for Android-Titanium

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, titanium-mobile

I am new to Titanium, I wanted to drag and drop pin and want to have its coordinates. I have code which works for iOS.

```
mapview.addEventListener('pinchangedragstate', function(evt)
{

    alert("pinchangedragstate Detected");
    if (evt.oldState == "dragging") {
        annotation.subtitle = [annotation.latitude, ':', annotation.longitude].join(' ');
    }
    Ti.API.info(['newState:', evt.newState, 'oldState', evt.oldState].join(' '));
});
```

Anyone know how to make similar this work for Android-Titanium?

Comment: Have you figure this out, asking because kind of facing the same problem !

Comment: Nope..I ditched the framework...